# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar datos en base a fecha en firebase?

Tags: firebase, ide

Estoy trabajando con sensores en ide, estos toman datos cada cierto tiempo, y a través de un nodemcu me conecto a firebase. Necesito que estos se guarden en base al día que son tomados, pero no se como hacer ese paso. (Estoy aprendiendo hace 2 semanas, mi área es totalmente distinta :C)

Answer (score 0):

La mejor práctica es guardar sus datos así ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
ref.child("yourNode").updateChildren(map);
```

También recuerde, cuando configura el TIMESTAMP, lo configura como un Map, pero cuando lo recupera, lo recupera como un Long. Para recuperar los datos, le sugiero que utilice este método:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timestamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

La clase de modelo debería verse así:

```
public class YourModelClass {
    //private fields
    private Map<String, String> timestamp;

    public YourModelClass() {}

    //public setters and getters for the fields

    public void setTimestamp(Map<String, String> timeStamp) {this.timestamp= timestamp;}
    public Map<String, String> getTimestamp() {return timestamp;}
}
```

Recuerde, ServerValue.TIMESTAMPes solo un token que Firebase Realtime Database convierte en un número en el lado del servidor cuando se usa como un valor secundario durante la operación de escritura. La fecha solo aparece en la base de datos después de que se completa la operación de escritura.

Para obtener el timestamp, también hay otro enfoque, que sería escribir una función en [Cloud Functions](http://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) para Firebase y será tan fácil como:

```
exports.currentTime = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send({"timestamp":new Date().getTime()})
})
```

Puede alojar esto en Cloud Function y obtener la marca de tiempo del servidor sin interacción del usuario.

Comment: SOS GROSOOOO! SABELO!!  tratare de asimilarlo e implementarlo

Comment: Gracias, espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: Por favor, evita responder a preguntas que no estén bien formadas o que no se ajusten a las normas/formato del sitio. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y así ganarás una nueva medalla). Saludos.